# Powershell: WQL output data not loading

Tags: powershell, wmi, wql

Below is my WQL query.

```
$SCCMQuery = @'
Select UAR.User, UAR.Application, UAR.CurrentState from sms_fullcollectionmembership as FCM
INNER JOIN SMS_UserApplicationRequest as UAR ON UAR.User=FCM.SMSID
where FCM.CollectionID="a\\100104"
'@
$Request = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\Site_Name" -Query $SCCMQuery
```

Now i want to pass this output to datagrid control.

```
foreach ($Request in $Requests) {
            $Array.Add($Request)
        }
        $dataGridView1.DataSource = $Array
        for ($i=0; $i -lt $dataGridView1.ColumnCount; $i++) {
            $dataGridView1.Columns[$i].width = 161
        }
```

It is not working properly.Data is loading in datagrid control but i think those are some system data.

e.g. System.Management.Scope and many more.

If i simply check the value of $Request then it is showing me all the data but it is not passing to datagrid control.

Please advise me on this.

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of what the DataGridView control looks like after population?

Comment: And an example of what the good data looks like for comparison.